# How to render an element when hovering over a disabled button?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, styled-components

I want to render an element when I hover hover a button when it is disabled.

My app component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
    
    const onHover = () => {
        setHover(true);
    };
    
    const onLeave = () => {
        setHover(false);
    };
    
    
    return (
        <div className="App" style={appStyles}>
            <StyledGlButton
                className = "dis-btn"
                onMouseEnter={onHover}
                onMouseLeave={onLeave}
                disabled = {isDisabled}
            >
                Red
            </StyledGlButton>
            {(hover && isDisabled) && ( 
                <h1>Disabled Button!!</h1>
            )}    
        </div>
    );
}
        
export default App;
```

and my StyledGlButton:

```
export const StyledGlButton = styled(GlButton)<GlButtonProps>`
    &.gl-cta {
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 3rem;
    min-height: auto;
    pointer-events: all !important;
}`;
```

I tried adding `pointer-events: all !important;` in the css of the button but it is not working.

Comment: Can you share your code and what you have tried so far?

Comment: a disabled button has no pointer events - it is disabled...

Comment: @tacoshy disabled means it can't be clicked, not that it can't be hovered.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly. We can not help you solve your problem based on nothing more than your overly vague verbal description of how you failed to achieve it.

Comment: but hovering is not a point event... I don't see how that would or should make another element become visible

Comment: @tacoshy it is an event occurring when the user uses their _pointer device_, which most commonly would be a mouse. Quote MDN: _"Pointer events are DOM events that are fired for a pointing device."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surround the `button` with `span` and give that button `pointer-events: none`, so the span can listen to the events.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const span = document.querySelector('span');
span.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  console.log('hovered');
});
```

```css
button {
  pointer-events:none
}
```

```html
<span><button disabled>Button</button></span>
```

Comment: the `<span>` trick works very good when the Button states are interfering with parent component. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I may well be that *React* simply disables the `mouseover` event of a *[disabled]* element by giving it `pointer-events: none`. I don't use *React*, but this is what I expect their solution to be.

Worse would be *React* catching the event in JS and doing nothing with it (would probably go against W3C specs). In that case the solution by @Mina would be best to use.

**`pointer-events: all`** as you mention is meant [for SVG elements only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#syntax), use **`pointer-events: auto`** instead.

Here's a little snippet that shows two `disabled` buttons and a hidden element that only shows when hovered over `disabled` button *two*.

```css
/* To prove a [disabled] element
   listens to 'mouseover' event */
button:hover         { color: red }

/* The hidden element */
.render              { display: none }
button:hover~.render { display: block }

/* Expected React 'disabled' solution */
.one { pointer-events: none }
/* To prove pointer events can be disabled */

/* Override(?) React solution */
.two:is(:disabled,
        [disabled],
        [disabled=true],
        [disabled="true"])
   { pointer-events: auto !important }
    /* !important may be required for React */
```

```html
<button class="one" disabled>one</button>
<button class="two" disabled>two</button>
<div class="render">rendered</div>
```